# Best way to assign a value to a property of all objects in a collection using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `Car` object with a `ResaleValue` property, and I have a collection of these car objects stored in:

```
 IEnumerable<Car>
```

I also have a ResaleCalculator() with a calculate method.

Is there a way in linq to apply a calculation and set the `ResaleValue` property of every object in the collection without a loop?

Comment: LINQ doesn't have to be used for everything.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't really want to use LINQ for this. Firstly, you're not avoiding a loop, you are merely abstracting it away. Secondly, LINQ methods are intended to filter and/or project a sequence, not mutate it. While you could use the `.ForEach` *instance method* on `List<T>` to not explicitly write a loop, it is hardly clearer than simply coding the loop to do what you need it to do.

Comment: it is the sort of thing that MoreLinq's `ForEach` operator is intended for.  But I'm sure Eric Lippert would agree with you as he stated this was pretty much the reason it wasn't included in the first place.

Comment: This is the best answer, my answer is only 'technically' correct. Interestingly, last time I took the stance of 'don't do that' I was down voted :o( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029217 And this time I took the other side, and for awhile was again downvoted. I just can't win :op

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify the `IEnumerable<T>` without projecting into a new IEnumerable with those values set to the `ResaleValue` property and copying over the existing properties. Ideally you would do this when you first get your `IEnumerable<Car>`.

```
IEnumerable<Car> cars = // however you set cars originally
cars = cars.Select(c => new Car
            {
                Prop1 = c.Prop1,
                Prop2 = c.Prop2,
                ResaleValue = ResaleCalculator(params)
             });
```

Clearly this is not ideal. On the other hand, you could `ToList()` your collection and use the `ForEach` method or a regular `foreach` loop:

```
var list = cars.ToList()
               .ForEach(c => c.ResaleValue = ResaleCalculator(c.SomeNeededParam));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do what you want

```
cars.Select(c=>c.ResaleValue = c.Calculate());
```

Comment: Oh my, the use of the `Select` operator to obtain a `Foreach` operator come hell or high water.  But I believe it is what the OP wants and does work, so +1.  (IMO, I'd create a `Foreach` extension method if you really want LINQ-style syntax to avoid confusing people by using a `Select` without making use of the projection.)

Comment: @Kirk, interesting, comment removed. But still evil.

Comment: @Anthony, maybe I shouldn't have +1'd, but I figured the proper answer (yours) would eventually be provided and I perversely like seeing all the options on the table for discussion. :)

Comment: I have to say I have never done this myself, its evil. Just like this while ((newLine = r.read()) != null)

Comment: @lain: Why is this evil: "while ((newLine = r.read()) != null)"?

Comment: Because I always end up starting at it wondering "What does that do?". I like things to be obvious.

Comment: @jangeador: Because it's mutating state, branching, and assigning in the same line of code. That's too much for one little line.

Comment: I've used this a lot. I got it straight from msdn. Thanks for clarifying this.